# Cautionary steps before computer repair: How to wipe everything from SSD of dead computer except for OS

Tags: ssd, formatting, repair, privacy-protection

After moving my PC build inches, my PC somehow refuses to boot. I can't diagnose what problem is specifically happening to the computer, so I plan on going to a PC repair shop to have them diagnose the problem. However, I want to make sure all my personal data is protected. To protect my data, I plan on wiping my SSD. Is it possible for me to wipe everything from my Samsung 850 EVO Pro 500GB without removing the Windows 10 Operating System from my dead computer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data security during laptop repair](https://superuser.com/questions/934370/data-security-during-laptop-repair)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for me to wipe everything from my Samsung 850 EVO Pro 500GB without removing the Windows 10 Operating System from my dead computer?

No, realistically speaking, not a chance.

You need another computer anyway and connect the drive via additional SATA, USB or other adapter. You wouldn't be booting from that drive and some Windows features - fast startup and user permissions - prevents accessing data leaving only format as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Might be interested to know that flash memory devices like SSD's can swap out available sectors at any time with no notice, rendering old data normally inaccessible and un-wipeable, but ultimately probably readable with special techniques.

Your real answer was to encrypt all sensitive data *before* writing it to the SSD, and don't give *anyone* the key (a guest / dummy account could suffice for repairs - and don't let them install key-loggers or other malware either).

Right now, you *might* be able to do a "Secure Erase" of the entire drive, quickly changing it's internal encryption key (no need to overwrite everything) and *maybe* rendering all old data unreadable. Then re-install just windows and then use encryption for your data in the future.

---

Reference: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108027/samsung-ssd-850-evo-best-way-to-protect-personal-data-against-thiefs

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion - why not simply remove the SSD from the box before taking it in?

It does't sound like an ssd related issue and they'll have other/spare drives on hand to test with and hopefully diagnose your issue (if all is found to be well then you know its SSD/Partition/OS/etc related). Quick/easy/private & you should still get your problem fixed - ticks all the boxes! :-)

Or with more details, I'd be surprised if somebody here couldn't help you figure it out...